# Bind a key combination to caps lock in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, key-binding

I've bound both caps lock and the ctrl key to "ctrl" in OSX, but I would like to be able to press a modifier key along with caps lock to turn on caps lock—say, for example, shift+caps lock. How might I be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::CONTROL_L, ModifierFlag::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::CAPSLOCK</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

`SHIFT_L` can also be replaced with `FN`.